# Should I use set_transient or update_option?

Tags: theme-development, themes, widgets

I want to store some Twitter API data in WordPress. After every hour, I want to fetch new data from Twitter, and update only if the data is successfully retrieved from API (sometimes the API gives error, so in that case I want to keep using the old data). 
So in that case should I use `set_transient` or `update_option`?

If I used `update_option` then at least I can check if new data is available before updating the option.

What happens if I `set_transient` for an hour and after one hour the new data is not available, will I lose the stored data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A transient is not like a [`wp_cron`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) job in that they don't update themselves when a set time has elapsed. A transient will update when an attempt is made to access the data. If you actually do need an approximately hourly update you will need to use [`wp_cron`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron), though in practice it may not matter much and you could use a [`wp_cron`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) job to update the transient if you wanted.

But to answer the question asked, when you run [`get_transient`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_transient) to check your transient value it will return `false` if ["the transient does not exist, does not have a value, or has expired"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_transient), but you don't know which, and running `get_transient` also runs [`delete_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_option) [if the timeout has expired](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/option.php#L459). I verified that the transient is in fact deleted from the database by setting up a 60 second timeout test, and checking the database itself for the transient.

Transients do have an advantage over normal options in terms of caching.

> Also of note is that Transients are inherently sped up by caching
>   plugins, where normal Options are not. A memcached plugin, for
>   example, would make WordPress store transient values in fast memory
>   instead of in the database. For this reason, transients should be used
>   to store any data that is expected to expire, or which can expire at
>   any time.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

This may not matter on your site in particular, but in general it does count toward using the Transients API. You will have to do something about the lost data issue, though. Something like...

```
function get_twit_wpse_94911() {
  $trans = 'test_transient';
  $data = get_option('_transient_'.$trans);
  if (empty($data)) {
    $data = 'Yay Awesome Data'; // default data if you want it
  }
  if (!get_transient($trans)) {
    // check for new information
    // $new = fetch_twitter_however_you_are_doing_it();
    // check for the integrity of the new data
    // !empty() may not be adequate
    if (!empty($new)) {
      $data = $new;
    }
    set_transient($trans,$data,60*60);
  }
  return get_transient($trans);
}
```

Comment: The **TL;DR** here is **use the Transients API for things that are intended to *expire***. Note: for external API data as (*ahem*) difficult to work with as the Twitter API, I have had luck setting *two* transients: a *short*-term transient (1 hour) and a *long*-term transient (24 hours). The long-term transient is the fallback for the short-term transient. If the third-party API can't return valid data once every 24 hours, then there's not much WordPress can do about it. The API is probably just crappy (looking at *you*, Twitter).