# WP_Cron doesn't do the job: Multisite stats

Tags: functions, wp-cron, transient

[I already found out how to get the amount of networkwide posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106346/network-wide-post-count-wp-multisite) in WPMS. Until now the function was called by a user who opens the website. So it was rebuild every 24 hours. I don't want to let a single user wait for half a minute until the process is done so I started to work with wp_cron. But there seems to be a problem because I can't see the result in the shortcode. It would be great if someone could take a look to the following lines:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wpms_stats_activation');
add_action('wpms_stats_daily_event', 'posts_count_func');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'wpms_stats_deactivation'); 

// Start the cron on activation
function wpms_stats_activation() {
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'wpms_stats_daily_event');
}

// Delete the cache and deactivate the cron
function my_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('wpms_stats_daily_event');
    delete_site_transient( 'total_posts_cache' );
}

// Count the posts of the whole network
function posts_count_func( $args ){

    global $wpdb;
    $blogs = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->blogs} WHERE  spam = '0' 
            AND deleted = '0' AND archived = '0' 
            ORDER BY registered DESC, 2", ARRAY_A ) );

    $original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

     $args = array(
        'numberposts'     => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'post',
        'post_status'     => 'publish' );
    $total_network = $draft_network = 0;
    $total_sites = 0;

    foreach ($blogs as $blog)
    {
        wp_cache_flush();
        switch_to_blog( $blog->blog_id );
        $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
        if (count(get_posts($args))<2) { continue; }
        $total_posts = count( get_posts( $args ) );
        $total_network += $total_posts;
        $total_sites += 1;

        $args['post_status'] = 'draft';

        }

        set_site_site_transient ( 'total_posts_cache', $total_network );


 switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id );
}

//Make a shortcode which shows the amount of posts
function posts_shortcode_count_func( $atts ){
    $post_count = get_site_transient( 'total_posts_cache' );
    return $post_count;
}
add_shortcode( 'posts', 'posts_shortcode_count_func' );
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It is [`set_site_transient`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_site_transient), not `set_site_site_transient`.

You should be aware that a single user will still wait that half a minute for this to complete. `wp_cron` does not run on clock time. It runs when a user visits the site.

If you have the ability to create a system `cron` job then hook your callback to an [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) action, and use the system `cron` to trigger it. That should give you a true clock-time activation and avoid having to force some unlucky user to wait.

## Related:

[WordPress Cron Schedule the if and else statement](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102589/wordpress-cron-schedule-the-if-and-else-statement/105708#105708)
[Should I use set_transient or update_option?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94911/should-i-use-set-transient-or-update-option/94917#94917)

Comment: Thank you! You're right, there has been `set_site_site_transient` twice. I'm wondering what is the best way to get and cache the posts count. E.g. is there a way to generate it by an external cron?

Comment: @Philipp : see the edit

Comment: Thanks again @s_ha_dum. I think this is to tricky for me at the moment. So I'll leave it as it is a tray it for a couple of days.